# Use Router With DDWRT As Repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have been trying to set up my router as a repeater using DDWRT.  I have followed multiple guides, but for whatever reason the SSID is not broadcasting and I am unable to use it as such.

Can someone point out to me what I mixed up so that it will succesfully work as a repeater?

These are steps I followed:

> Setup > Basic setup: 
>   Connection Type : Automatic Configuration DHCP 
>   STP: Disable
>   Router Name : Repeater 
>   Router IP: 
>   Local IP Address: 192.168.1.120 
>   Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0 
>   Gateway: 192.168.1.254  
>   Local DNS: 192.168.1.254  
>   Network Address Server Settings
>   DHCP Type= DHCP Server 
>   Start ip address: 192.168.1.200  
>   Maximum DHCP Users: 44 
>   
>   Setup>Advanced Routing: 
>   Operating mode: Rip2 Router 
>   
>   Wireless > Basic settings 
>   Regulatory Domain: 
>   Wireless Mode: Client Bridge  
>   Wireless Network Name: Net 
>   Virtual Interfaces: 
>   Wireless Network Name(SSID): Net2
>   Wireless Mode: AP 
>   
>   Wireless > Wireless Security  
>   Wireless Security (ath0) 
>   Security Mode (WPA Personal) 
>   WPA Algorithms: TKIP 
>   WPA Shared Key: pippo 
>   Virtual Interfaces (ath1) 
>   Security Mode: WPA Personal 
>   WPA Algorithms: TKIP 
>   WPA Shared Key: pluto

Status>Wireless>Site Survey>Join to the SSID of main router for connect fonera

Comment: Why have you configured it as a DHCP server?!

Comment: I followed a tutorial I found here http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=39507 --- Should I disable the DHCP server?

Comment: Did you read the thread, "*These instructions are incorrect and out of date.*".

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but have been unable to find a complete working tutorial on the setup.

Comment: Also, unless your existing AP is using WPA/TKIP (which I sure hope it isn't), those settings can't possibly be right either.

Comment: My current router is set to WPA-TKIP.

Comment: If at all possible, you should change that.

Comment: I just set it to WPA2-PSK [AES]

Comment: That will definitely help. Lots of things don't work with TKIP.